# how to enable and disable link by click button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        `$('#button1').click(function(){             
             $("a").removeAttr('href');
         }       
       });
    });
</script>`

<a href="https://youtube.com">link</a>`
<input id="button1" type="button" class="add" value="Click to remove the link!" />
```

Comment: Rolled back the last edit.  While the edit "fixed" things, it changed the original content the author provided.  Please leave any errors the author has in their question, in the question.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, you can "comment", pointing out an error, particularly if it's just a typo, or add an "answer", with the fix, especially if it's substantial. Leaving the original question interact allows more than 1 solution to be provided, AND leaves the question interact for future visitors, who may have similar questions. It also prevents confusion, and keeps Answers valid, as Answers are a response to the question on is original form.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a class with `pointer-events:none`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $("a").toggleClass('disable');

  });
});
```

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"> Link</a>
<button id='button1'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle the application of the [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) style using JQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#toggle").on("click", function(event){
       $("a").toggleClass("disable");
    });
});
```

```css
/* When applied to an element, the element doesn't respond to mouse actions */
.disable { pointer-events:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com">Example.com</a>
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="Enable/Disable Link">
```

But, if you are asking how to remove the link altogether, then you would use the `.remove()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btnRemove").on("click", function(){
      $("a").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com">Example.com</a>
 <input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="Click to remove the link!">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need u disable and enable the link when clicking button  plsss help me